# How to make an input add text automaticly when pressing down a key?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got this "full-screen overlay search box" in my nav. So whenever you hit this magnifying glass a fullscreen overlay with an input search will come up (can't post images yet, but it looks something like this: https://assets.wordpress.envato-static.com/uploads/2017/01/02-clickmag-demo-search.jpg).

Anyway, when you enter this "fullscreen" I want the Input to react and add text whenever a key is pressed down. Right now I'll have to click on the placeholder and then write whatever I'm searching for. Instead, I want it to automatically react and ad

```css
body{
background: white;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
padding-bottom: -1px;
}
.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
header{
  background: #fff;
}
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
header ::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav{
float: right;
padding-right: 230px;
}
nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 25px;

}
nav a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a:hover{
  color: red;
}
nav li:hover{
}

.fa-bars{
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.fa-bars:hover{
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}





.bild1{
  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 80px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 4;
  background-image: url('Img/KBA.jpg');
  background-position: 10% 30% ;
  background-size: 180%;

}

.bild2{
  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-left: 120px;
 z-index: 3;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #3D6BB8;

}

.entrytext{
float: right;
margin-right: 90px;
margin-top: 175px;
clear: both;


}
.entrytext>h1{
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 54px;
}

.entrytext>button{
border: none;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #38b272;
color: white;
padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
letter-spacing: 6px;
border-radius: 8px;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 17px;
text-align: left;
margin-top:   20px;
box-shadow: 20px 15px black;
}

.entrytext>button:hover{
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c12147;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
button:focus {outline:0;}

.fa-angle-right{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;

}


.entrytext>h2{
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 600;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.citygalleria{
  color: #CC2244;
}


.brand{
  height: 110px;
  width: 750px;
  margin: 600px auto;

  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  clear: both;
}




.openBtn {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openBtn:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;

  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}


.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 46%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

.overlay .closebtn:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.overlay input[type=text] {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  background:none;
  margin: 0 auto;
   text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  color:black;
text-align:center;
  width: 30%;


}
input::placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.overlay input[type=text]:hover {
  background: none;
}

.overlay button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:focus {outline:0;}

.overlay button:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/908c2e5c96.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <title>Kungsmässan — Måste upplevas!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<header>

<div class="container">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Butiker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resturang & Café</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Utbyggnad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Öppetider</a></li>





    <div id="myOverlay" class="overlay">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="closeSearch()" title="Close Overlay">×</span>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input onblur="this.placeholder = 'Sök'" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" type="text" placeholder="Sök" name="search">

    </form>
  </div>
</div>

   <i onclick="openSearch()" id="openBtn" class="fas fa-search"></i>


   <script>
function openSearch() {
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
}

function closeSearch() {
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>


      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">

</div>
  <div class="bild1">
  </div>
  <div class="bild2">
  </div>
  <div class="entrytext">
    <h1>Sveriges bästa <br/> <span class="citygalleria">citygalleria.</span> Mitt  <br/> i Kungsbacka.</h1>
    <h2>35 000 KVADRATMETER OCH ÖVER 100 AFFÄRER!</h2>
    <button type="LÄS MER" name="button ">LÄS MER<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
  </div>

<div class="brand">

</div>



  </body>
</html>
```

d text, as I said^. I guess there's a way to achieve this but I dunno how ;)

Would love if someone could help me out!

Comment: You should add some html to your question so we know what you have so far and include what you've tried. Helpers aren't here to write full solutions. Sounds like you're looking for some way of `setting focus` to the textbox when the form opens.

Comment: I mean, the code doesn't really matter as I'm just interested in how to make it work. The search placeholder should be there when it opens, but whenever you hit a key on your keyboard it disappears and you can start writing, like a trigger.

Comment: There might be 10 ways or more or less. This site is for answering specific coding questions, not 'how should i do this'. sux i know, but your question will probably be closed if there's no coding question.

Comment: Sure, will send tomorrow!

Comment: Elements input.oninput event ?  Maybe can help it video https://youtu.be/GQSUT6svyCI

Comment: Not really, I don't think you get me. It should just automatic put in the text without pressing the placeholder before.

Comment: Now I've added my code!

Comment: Just add a keydown event handler and change the input value when a specific key is pressed? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I don't even know how to create it. Maybe you can show me ?

Comment: Would appreciate if you added it to my code and showed me :)

Comment: @filip Made an example for you when pressing the a or b key. https://jsfiddle.net/9hmkxpLj/

Comment: @MarkBaijens That's not really what I'm trying to achieve. I don't want the text "a pressed to be added into the textbox". I'll try to explain one more time :)
So you got this textbox in your example, then I want the text to be added without even hovering/clicking or making focus on the textbox by using the mouse. Instead, I want the focus to start whenever I press a key. So conclusion: I want the text to automatically to be added into the text box whenever a key is pressed down, without clicking on the placeholder. 

get me? :)

Comment: @filip you can focus an element pragmatically with the `focus()` function. If that does not help you a recommend to open a new question with the guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As a beginner in Javascript, I would like if you showed me how to do it? You said earlier that you needed my code, so feel free to use it now. I don't know if you still don't get me if so that's weird. it's simple as it should be explained, whenever the overlay search box is opened you see the placeholder "Sök" (see code^). Here comes what I wanna achieve: Without pressing the placeholder and then write what I'm looking to search for, I want the text to be added into the textbox whenever I hit a key (WITHOUT PRESSING THE PLACE HOLDER BEFORE). :)

Comment: @filip Because the question is closed I cannot post a proper answer. I voted for a reopen, but need someone else to vote for that too. Maybe this fiddle helps. https://jsfiddle.net/6u8qs3k7/

Answer (score 0):

so I don't see any nav bar with a clickable magnifying glass, but I'd imagine you would have a piece of HTML that will trigger a function that will show the overlay.

Someting along the lines of

```
<nav>
   <ul>
   <li id="magnifying-glass"></li>
   (...)
</nav>



  <div id="overlay-content">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input id="overlay-input" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Sök'" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" type="text" placeholder="Sök" name="search">

    </form>
  </div>

<script>
   document.getElementById("magnifying-glass").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById("overlay-content").style.display="block"; //assuming it was "none" before through css
       document.getElementById("overlay-input).focus();
   });

</script>
```

I wrote this in SO's editor so I probably made some syntactical errors, but the key is the use of the `.focus()` function that'll do what you want I think. It should be executed after you show the overview.

Learn some more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus